# How to include custom configuration files for packages in .iso installation file

Tags: linux, debian, iso-image

The [following guide](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Modify/CD) boils down to modifying an .iso to essentially adding the packages you need to the /pool/main folder, and then fixing various metadata files throughout the file.

However, I am looking for a deeper custom configuration - as an example, I would like to have a custom systemd service included, certain users already created with specified permissions (e.g. in the audio group), /etc/network/interfaces set, and other package configuration files written as well.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: So.. not an answer because I am too lazy to do it for you.  Perhaps someone else might but the guide tells you how to add .deb packages to the ISO and set the install priority.  Script your requirements into a .deb package and set it to required for the install.  Yes, a dpkg run script (howbeit frowned upon) can create your service entries and user creation along with dropping files wherever you want them.  You can even script the uninstall (which you should) where the added users might be removed along with the other configurations.  Start on an already installed debian and get .deb working.

Comment: Also.. a debian VM (like virtualbox) is very useful with checkpoints while working on a .deb installer.  You might hose your stuff while figuring your package out.

Comment: Thanks for the info sir. Can you elaborate on what you mean by a dpkg run script ? From what I know dpkg is used to install and manage existing packages on a debian system (e.g. `dpkg -i, dpkg -l` commands) I don't know how this cmd line utility would be able to affect configuration scripts in let's say the apache2 package.

Comment: A debian package is a .deb file installed/uninstalled by the dpkg tool (even if you type `apt-get` or `apt` to run it).  It is a simple compressed file of the tree you want to lay down and a few script "slots" for before the install, after the install, before the uninstall, and after the uninstall.  It is actually quite simple (more than RPM).  You will probably need to author a .deb installer that does everything you need first.. (and test it) then add it to the ISO.  You must understand that my eyes glazed over looking at the guide so guessing.  I have written many deb packages.

Comment: Alright then, I'll (figure out how to and) build a debian package that does everything I need and then add it to the .iso

Comment: Once you do solve this, please come back and write yourself an answer.  You will get the points AND it will help future people searching for the same thing. :)